# Multiple ifelse to build an additional vector to add as a column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I wrote an function which is checking each row of a data.frame. The checks are conditional statements which print YES or NO. Should be very straight forward. But somehow the results are not what was intended. I've tried 2 different ways.

Please find some test data here: [TEST TABLE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgi0nz9yj4xwuvh/test.csv?dl=0)

```
add_accepted_column <- function(df){
  shopmanager_status <- df[28]
  source_medium <- df[22]
  campaign <- df[23]
  click_to_conversion <- df[29]
  accepted <- c()
  if(shopmanager_status %in% c("complete","processing") & source_medium %in% c("tradetracker / nl", "google / organic", "bing / organic", "yahoo / organic")){
      accepted <- c(accepted,"YES")
  }
  else if(shopmanager_status %in% c("complete","processing") & click_to_conversion < 1){
    accepted <- c(accepted,"YES")
  } 
  else if(shopmanager_status %in% c("complete","processing") & campaign %in% c("1.Top-Brand")){
    accepted <- c(accepted,"YES")
  } else{
    accepted <- c(accepted,"NO")
  }
}

# 
 add_accepted_column <- function(df){
   shopmanager_status <- df[28]
   source_medium <- df[22]
   campaign <- df[23]
   click_to_conversion <- df[29]
   #print(class(click_to_conversion))
   accepted <- c()
   accepted <- c(accepted,if_else(shopmanager_status %in% c("complete","processing") &
                   source_medium %in% c("tradetracker / nl", "google / organic", "bing / organic", "yahoo / organic") ||
                     click_to_conversion < 1 ||
                     campaign %in% c("1.Top-Brand"),"YES","NO"))
   return(accepted)
 }
```

It is super weird that for example `google / cpc` Give me a YES.

The actual rules i want to apply:

•   IF shopmanager_status IN ("complete","processing") AND IF(source_medium IN ("tradetracker / nl", "google / organic", "bing / organic", "yahoo / organic") --> YES

•   IF shopmanager_status IN ("complete","processing") AND IF(click_to_conversion < 1 ) --> YES

•   IF shopmanager_status IN ("complete","processing AND (campaign IN ("1.Top-Brand") --> YES

•   REST --> NO

If more examples are needed im happy to supply. Somehow I cant find out what is going on with the IF ELSE statements.

Comment: I get Warning message:
In if (shopmanager_status %in% c("complete", "processing") & click_to_conversion <  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: In the first version, you don't return the result, and you only calculate the value for the first line. In the second, you use "||", so it returns a single value, again only calculating the value of the first row. Moreover, the logic is completely different from the first - second always accepts if `click_to_conversion` < 1, but the first only if `shopmanager_status` is complete or processing. Please specify what exactly the conditions are.

Comment: @ChristophWolk the first is leading i will edit the post. Thanks!

Comment: I want to have a single value per ROW. Basically i just want to add a column saying Yes or No depending on the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df$accepted <- df$shopmanager_transaction_status %in% c("complete","processing") &
  (df$sourceMedium %in% c("tradetracker / nl", "google / organic", 
                          "bing / organic", "yahoo / organic") | 
   df$click_to_conversion_date < 1 | df$campaign == "1.Top-Brand")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work nicely. Thanks. Still prefer another syntax for bit more easy reading. But this does the trick!